# Copy data field of a form into another page's form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

As the title says, I would like to copy the values of a form when the user clicks the submit button into another form that is placed into another page and then auto submit this second form.
Is it possible? I have no idea how to do it, any suggestion or code example will be very nice!

Comment: can you explain more what is this "another page"  ? And what is the logic behind in doing so ?

Comment: Are you submitting data to your server after clicking submit and expecting the submitted information to be present on the next page? Or is it just a client-side copy. If its just client side you can store your data in localStorage and access it in next form.

Comment: @Java Main - with "another page" I mean another html page with a <form action="myaction" etc...>...</form> where the fields of this form are filled in by the fields of the original page.

Comment: you can access the "other page " via JQuery   like so   $.get('a.html', null, function(text){
    alert($(text).find('#name'));
});

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible if you have control over the origination form, the processing logic, and the page that has the secondary form you'd want to receive.

I think the flow would be something like this:
User submits form > form gets processed and does what it needs to do > form logic then redirects to a url with GET/POST variables.  The receiving page first checks for the presence of GET/POST variables and if found puts them into the form accordingly.

What language are you using to process the form? I can create a more elaborate answer with a little more info.

Comment: Unfortunatly I do not have control on the origination form. I just can use Jquery to copy the first forms data somewhere else into another form in the same page, but I don't know how I can execute 2 different actions on submit the first form. I'm using Joomla and custom html+jquery code.